# Using declaration in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

```
namespace A {
  void F() {}
  namespace B {
    void F(int) {}  
  }
}

using A::B::F;

namespace A {
  void G() {
    F();   // OK
    F(1);  // Error: too many arguments to function void A::F()
  }
}

int main() { return 0; }
```

I have this piece of code.

I defined two functions with same names but different signatures.

Then I use a using-declaration `using A::B::F`.

In `A::G()` compiler tries to resolve `A::F()` before `A::B::F()`.

Are there any orders if there are such conflicts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deepest nested scope is searched first, and scopes are then searched outward if the name is not found. So first it would find a block-scope declaration of `F` inside `G`, if any; then it would find a declaration at the namespace scope of `A`, if any; and if that too failed it would search the global scope. Since `using A::B::F;` appears at global scope, `A::F` is always found first. Perhaps you should move the `using` declaration inside `A`.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely about placement.

```
namespace A {
  void G() {


    F();   // OK, A::F

    using B::F;
    F(1);  // OK, A::B::F
  }
}
```